# How to update my data frame as changing its rows place in pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

would you please help me to convert my input to the output as follow with Python Pandas?
Thank you

Input (what data i have)

[image]

output(what data i expect)

[image]

I really appreciate your help. Thanks alot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: In addition to what @Yevhen said, [please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341); instead post the text itself and use [code formatting](/editing-help#code). It's also not even clear how the output follows from the input, like, do you want to select the `BG NUMBERS` where `BG LIST` starts with `EG`, or do you want to make groups where `B G` occurs and select the first `BG NUMBERS` element? That sort of info should be included in the question.

Comment: Sorry, i will follow the how to ask rules next time. i am pretty new here in stackoverflow . Thank you for letting me know

Comment: @hilhil can your clarify the logic? And maybe replace your images with text? Have you tested the solution below?

Answer (score 2):

Use boolean indexing after shifting your "BG NUMBERS" column up:

```
m = df['BG LIST'].eq('BG')

out = (df.assign(**{'BG NUMBERS': df['BG NUMBERS'].shift(-1)})
         .loc[m]
       )
```

Comment: Looks like `.eq('B G')` (in the input but not in the output :-))

Comment: @Corralien I wondered the same, looks like `BG` in the output though. OP should provide a reproducible input...